# Protein that exit from the cell - as marker

Tags: proteins

Searching for some protein, that I could use as extracellular marker for mammalian cells. I need to insert mRNA to cell, and to detect the protein outside the cell (not on membrane) if the mRNA successfully enter and been translated. (not GFP, I need protein that exit from the cell in big numbers)

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to check secretome analyses like http://www.nature.com/nbt/journal/v30/n10/full/nbt.2356.html

Comment: I don't know of any that are exported by all cells, e.g. both neurons and . All blood proteins, e.g. serum albumin are exported but by specific cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always express GFP or your favorite protein in a secretory vector like [`pSecTag`](https://www.lifetechnologies.com/order/catalog/product/K602501) or [`pSecTag2`](https://www.lifetechnologies.com/order/catalog/product/V90020) from Invitrogen/Life/ThermoFisher/SuperUltraBioMegaMart. There are probably others, but those were the first ones I came across. They contain the mouse Igκ signal sequence for efficient secretion (so the website says, I've never used it).

I don't know the details of your experiment, but are you sure you want to use a secreted protein as a transfection marker? Remember, it's possible that only a small fraction of your cell population will take up the vector (or mRNA, if that's what you're using, but there are [issues](http://www.invivogen.com/review-tlr7-tlr8) with that), but you will see secreted protein regardless of the number of cells that take it up.

Comment: Thank you! Looks good. It's ok, I just need to know if some cells get the vector, doesn't meter how many of them.

Answer (score 1):

SEAP, secreted alkaline phosphatase, and vectors engineered to express fusions to this reporter gene may be well-suited to solve your problem.